# Restcomm RVD is not running from docker container

Tags: docker, restcomm

I am running restcomm docker container in AMI where. I have created the container by default setting.

Using the default values:

```
 docker run --name=restcomm -d -p 8080:8080 -p 5080:5080 -p 5082:5082 -p 5080:5080/udp -p 65000-65535:65000-65535/udp gvagenas/restcomm:7.3.0
```

i have not been able to access the RVD by

http://x.x.x.x:8080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the command mentioned in http://www.telestax.com/rapid-webrtc-application-development-with-restcomm-and-docker/ ie

```
docker run –name=restcomm -d -e STATIC_ADDRESS=”YOUR_HOST_IP_ADDRESS_HERE” -p 8080:8080 -p 5080:5080 -p 5082:5082 -p 5080:5080/udp -p 65000-65535:65000-65535/udp gvagenas/restcomm
```

Comment: dashboard is not appearing. remember docker is running amazone instance and i am trying both public ip and public DNS. and actual command is like this: docker run --name=restcomm -d -e STATIC_ADDRESS="52.68.60.85" -p 8080:8080 -p 5080:5080 -p 5082:5082 -p 5080:5080/udp -p 65000-65535:65000-65535/udp gvagenas/restcomm:7.3.0

Comment: you can use -e STATIC_ADDRESS=`curl http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4`, please make sure you opened the ports in the security group of your amazon instance otherwise the firewall will block you.

Comment: Are you there, jeand?

Comment: did you see my comment from yesterday just above your last comment ? Did you try that ?

Comment: Actually the team just released a new version see http://www.telestax.com/telscale-restcomm-7-4-0-ga-released/ so you pull  the latest or 7.4.0 ytag from docker hub

Comment: Many thanks jeand!!! I have got the console but have not been logged in by: u/n: administrator@company.com. and password: AMI instance id/docker container id. please advise. thanks

Comment: for docker the default password is RestComm. Feel free to upvote if that worked for you.

Comment: I found it already. I have marked answered. how do i vote it?

Comment: Great. Click the up arrow and that will do it. Thanks !